# Seekbar and Spinner cleared by a button JAVA Android Studio

Tags: java, android, android-spinner, android-seekbar

I'm trying to reset the seekbar, spinner and textview using a button. With the code I have implemented resets the seekbar and spinner to the position at the first click but it wont reset the textview in the first click. If I click the reset button a second time it will reset the textview.

```
public void handleReset(View v){
    Integer zeroNum = 0, oneNum = 1;
    Double Small = 2.99,oneOunce= 0.15;

    totalTextView.setText(Double.toString(Small + oneOunce));
  
   sizeSpinner.setSelection(zeroNum) ;
   seekbar.setProgress(oneNum);
   
}
```

I want everything to reset async.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the way how to reset the seekbar, spinner and textview with a button. Look at the code below.

```
public void handleReset(View v){
    String result;
    int zeroNum = 0, oneNum = 1;
    Double Small = 2.99,oneOunce= 0.15, subTotal;
    subTotal = Small + oneOunce;
    try{
        sizeSpinner.setSelection(zeroNum) ;
        flavorSpinner.setSelection(zeroNum);
        seekbar.setProgress(oneNum);
        peanutsCheckbox.setChecked(false);
        mmsCheckbox.setChecked(false);
        almondsCheckbox.setChecked(false);
        brownieCheckbox.setChecked(false);
        strawberriesCheckbox.setChecked(false);
        oreosCheckbox.setChecked(false);
        gummybearsCheckbox.setChecked(false);
        marshmallowsCheckbox.setChecked(false);
    }catch (NumberFormatException e){
        Toast.makeText(this, "Incorrect key", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }finally {
        result = numFormat.format(subTotal);
        totalTextView.setText(result);
    }
}
```